# JQuery selecting element based on url of background-image

Tags: jquery, url, background-image, selector

I'm trying to select an element based on its background-image. That image is defined inline.

```
<div class="el" style="background-image:url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg);"></div>
```

I've already tried using the common solutions but with no result.

```
$('.el').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).css('background-image') === 'http://cl.ly/010.jpg' ) console.log('found it');
});
```

or

```
var current = $('.el').css('background-image', 'url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg)');
```

jQuery doesn't find the image. I've even tried to iterate trough every single element and I've double checked the url. Everything seems fine so far.

Any Ideas what could be wrong here ?

Thank you

Comment: can you show the HTML?

Comment: @evan i have multiple divs with the same class and different background-images as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if ($(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg)') console.log('found it');
```

with  `url()` in search the string.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Yes i made a typo here in the forum but not im my code. I’ve tried your solutions and the thing i've forgotten was the url in the search string. That simple. Thank you @musa and co

Answer (score 1):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buieb/74mqm/3) for a working example.

You were missing quotes on the .el selector on this line:

```
var current = $('.el').css('background-image') === "url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg)"
```

Edit: You fixed the quotes, but in the second code block, you had only the URL, not the actual CSS value "url(...)". It should look like:

```
$('.el').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg)' ) console.log('found    it');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the url when you are checking. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vL4pG/

```
$('.el').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.css('background-image') === 'url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg)'){
         alert('found it');   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var current = $('.el').css('background-image') === "url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg)"
```

Here's a fiddle (used a different address for the image)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/sg4Qs/2/)

For your code, the first is incorrect because you need the url() wrapper, like this:

```
$('.el').each(function() {
if ( $(this).css('background-image') === 'url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg)' ) console.log('found    it');
});
```

Your second is incorrect because you are missing the quotes on the class, should be this:

```
var current = $('.el').css('background-image', 'url(http://cl.ly/010.jpg)');
```

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks. Was a typo in the forum. But the url in the search string, thats the solution. Thank you.